# Apache Derby CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not working in BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers at runtime

Tags: triggers, timestamp, derby

Apache Derby version 10.14.2.0.

I have several triggers I used in DB2 LUW, DB2 zOS, Oracle DB and MS SQL Server that set timestamp columns before inserts and before updates.  When trying to do similar in DerbyDB and use CURRENT_TIMESAMP the triggers deploy but at run time I get issues/errors.

Example deployment:
CREATE TABLE TEST1
(
ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1 ) ,
UNIQUE_ID VARCHAR (47) NOT NULL ,
CREATETIME TIMESTAMP WITH DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
MODIFYTIME TIMESTAMP ,
ENDTIME TIMESTAMP ,
STATUS NUMERIC (10) WITH DEFAULT 0
);
ALTER TABLE TEST1
ADD CONSTRAINT TEST1_PK PRIMARY KEY
(
ID
)
;

CREATE TRIGGER TEST1_BINS_TRG1
NO CASCADE BEFORE INSERT ON TEST1
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
VALUES NEW.MODIFYTIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;

CREATE TRIGGER TEST1_BUPD_TRG1
NO CASCADE BEFORE UPDATE OF STATUS
ON TEST1
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
WHEN ( NEW.STATUS >= 0 AND OLD.STATUS <> 9 )
VALUES NEW.STATUS = 9 , NEW.MODIFYTIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NEW.ENDTIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;

BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER TEST:
INSERT INTO DMKASL.TEST1 (UNIQUE_ID) VALUES ('1');
ISSUE: Fails to set MODIFYTIME with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, no errors

BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER TEST:
UPDATE DMKASL.TEST1 SET STATUS=1 WHERE UNIQUE_ID='1';
ERROR: SQL Error [30000] [22005]: An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'long' from a data value of type 'TIMESTAMP'.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or are BEFORE triggers not allowed to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

The derby.log with derby.language.logStatementText=true enabled shows this:
Tue Nov 28 12:14:28 EST 2023 Thread[DRDAConnThread_4,5,main] (XID = 230), (SESSIONID = 7), (DATABASE = data/test1), (DRDAID = ????????.????-723670463931461008{4}), Begin compiling prepared statement: UPDATE DMKASL.TEST1 SET STATUS=1 WHERE UNIQUE_ID='1' :End prepared statement
Tue Nov 28 12:14:28 EST 2023 Thread[DRDAConnThread_4,5,main] (XID = 230), (SESSIONID = 7), (DATABASE = data/test1), (DRDAID = ????????.????-723670463931461008{4}), End compiling prepared statement: UPDATE DMKASL.TEST1 SET STATUS=1 WHERE UNIQUE_ID='1' :End prepared statement
Tue Nov 28 12:14:28 EST 2023 Thread[DRDAConnThread_4,5,main] (XID = 230), (SESSIONID = 7), (DATABASE = data/test1), (DRDAID = ????????.????-723670463931461008{4}), Executing prepared statement: UPDATE DMKASL.TEST1 SET STATUS=1 WHERE UNIQUE_ID='1' :End prepared statement
Tue Nov 28 12:14:28 EST 2023 Thread[DRDAConnThread_4,5,main] (XID = 230), (SESSIONID = 7), (DATABASE = data/test1), (DRDAID = ????????.????-723670463931461008{4}), Executing prepared statement: VALUES  CAST (org.apache.derby.iapi.db.Factory::getTriggerExecutionContext().getNewRow().getObject(3) AS NUMERIC(10,0))  >= 0 AND CAST (org.apache.derby.iapi.db.Factory::getTriggerExecutionContext().getOldRow().getObject(3) AS NUMERIC(10,0))  <> 9  :End prepared statement
Tue Nov 28 12:14:28 EST 2023 Thread[DRDAConnThread_4,5,main] (XID = 230), (SESSIONID = 7), (DATABASE = data/test1), (DRDAID = ????????.????-723670463931461008{4}), Executing prepared statement: VALUES CAST (org.apache.derby.iapi.db.Factory::getTriggerExecutionContext().getNewRow().getObject(3) AS NUMERIC(10,0))  = 9 , CAST (org.apache.derby.iapi.db.Factory::getTriggerExecutionContext().getNewRow().getObject(1) AS TIMESTAMP)  = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CAST (org.apache.derby.iapi.db.Factory::getTriggerExecutionContext().getNewRow().getObject(2) AS TIMESTAMP)  = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP :End prepared statement
Tue Nov 28 12:14:28 EST 2023 Thread[DRDAConnThread_4,5,main] (XID = 230), (SESSIONID = 7), (DATABASE = data/test1), (DRDAID = ????????.????-723670463931461008{4}), Committing
Tue Nov 28 12:14:28 EST 2023 Thread[DRDAConnThread_4,5,main] (XID = 234), (SESSIONID = 7), (DATABASE = data/test1), (DRDAID = ????????.????-723670463931461008{4}), Begin compiling prepared statement: call SYSIBM.SQLCAMESSAGE(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) :End prepared statement
Tue Nov 28 12:14:28 EST 2023 Thread[DRDAConnThread_4,5,main] (XID = 234), (SESSIONID = 7), (DATABASE = data/test1), (DRDAID = ????????.????-723670463931461008{4}), End compiling prepared statement: call SYSIBM.SQLCAMESSAGE(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) :End prepared statement
Tue Nov 28 12:14:28 EST 2023 Thread[DRDAConnThread_4,5,main] (XID = 234), (SESSIONID = 7), (DATABASE = data/test1), (DRDAID = ????????.????-723670463931461008{4}), Executing prepared statement: call SYSIBM.SQLCAMESSAGE(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) :End prepared statement with 16 parameters begin parameter #1: -20001 :end parameter begin parameter #2: 20 :end parameter begin parameter #3: longTIMESTAMP22005 :end parameter begin parameter #4: CSS10140 :end parameter begin parameter #5: 0 :end parameter begin parameter #6: 0 :end parameter begin parameter #7: 0 :end parameter begin parameter #8: 0 :end parameter begin parameter #9: 0 :end parameter begin parameter #10: 0 :end parameter begin parameter #11:             :end parameter begin parameter #12: 22005 :end parameter begin parameter #13: NULL :end parameter begin parameter #14: en_US :end parameter begin parameter #15: NULL :end parameter begin parameter #16: null :end parameter logging

Comment: There's some discussion of this on the Apache mailing list here: https://lists.apache.org/thread/1rrj6b885wolw6jhxgwqgctokl8kqt55

Comment: yes, that is mine discussion in parallel.  Basically I have only got back suggestions to not use Before triggers so seems like they deply but really don't work.   Shame.